# Registering receiver app on Google cast sdk developer console

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

What should I enter in iOS app url, while creating a receiver application at Google Cast SDK Developer Console?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this, In my case the app isn't published yet, and so there isn't any url to enter !!!

Answer (score -1):

You can enter your App Url for that field for iOS.